# vaadin label text not wrapping

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

As it says on the tin.. I cannot get a label's text to wrap. Essentially I am building like a comments panel, user enters a comment and its displayed with timestamp etc.

I want the labels to both display with `ContentMode.PREFORMATTED` but also wrap.

The layouts of which contain the label are fixed width (100%) as is the label obviously by default, from what I have readin the book of vaadin what I am doing should work?

here is my code snippet:

```
VerticalLayout container = new VerticalLayout();
rootLayout.addComponent(container);

VerticalLayout comment = new VerticalLayout();
container.addComponent(comment);

Label createdByLbl = new Label(entity.getManagedMetadata().getAttrValue("createdBy") + " said:");
createdByLbl.setId("conversation.comment.username." + repositoryUID);
createdByLbl.setStyleName("conversation-comment-username");

Label createdDateLbl = new Label(entity.getManagedMetadata().getAttrValue("createdDate"));
createdDateLbl.setId("conversation.comment.createddate." + repositoryUID);
createdDateLbl.setSizeUndefined();

String text = entity.getDataNode().getAttrValue("text");
Label textLbl = new Label(text, ContentMode.PREFORMATTED);
textLbl.setId("conversation.comment.text." + repositoryUID);

comment.addComponent(createdByLbl);
comment.addComponent(textLbl);
comment.addComponent(createdDateLbl);

comment.setExpandRatio(createdByLbl, 0.2f);
comment.setExpandRatio(textLbl, 0.7f);
comment.setExpandRatio(createdDateLbl, 0.1f);
```

Note the container is also wrapped by  CssLayout (`rootLayout`), which is full sized.

I want the `textLbl` as seen above to display as formatted should the user enter text on separate lines themselves and wrap if they have entered a long paragraph comment.

Here is a picturing showing my dilemma.

[image: example]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: use css: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with css.
For example:

```
textLbl.addStyleName("wrapLine");
```

Css:

```
.wrapLine{
   word-wrap: break-word; /* IE  */
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: I tried applying the suggested solution. It did not work for me as the word wrapping was deactivated by another style - one that is applied when the width is undefined. So for me the solution was to simply use textLbl.setWidth("100%");